# Two Level class and interface extension throwing dart2js error because of different interfaces

Tags: inheritance, interface, dart, dart2js

I am having the following situation which is a bit hard to explain, but I will try anyway to make it as clear as I can.

I am working on a package for WebRTC that should be building dart applications. It was already done but I decided to rewrite the package with the following concepts:

- Provide only interfaces to the user and one public class that can be instantiated
- Leave implementation open for within the package
- Thus we have to implement interfaces at some point in the private implementations

I rewrote most of my classes (added an _) and created interfaces for all of the classes and let the original classes implement these interfaces.

The problem is now, that I have a basic implementation that I want to extend internally and also make available through extended interfaces. The code looks something like this:

```dart
// --- Basic implementation

abstract class Peer { }

abstract class P2PClient<P extends Peer> { }

// --- Protocol extension

abstract class ProtocolPeer
    extends Peer {
}

abstract class ProtocolP2PClient<P extends ProtocolPeer>
    extends P2PClient<P> {
}

/**
 * Implementations
 */

class _Peer implements Peer {
}

class _P2PClient<P extends _Peer>
    implements P2PClient<Peer> {
}

/**
 * -----
 */

class _ProtocolP2PClient
    extends _P2PClient<_ProtocolPeer>
    implements ProtocolP2PClient<ProtocolPeer> {
}

class _ProtocolPeer
    extends _Peer
    implements ProtocolPeer {
}
```

When I now try to compile this to JavaScript with dart2js it gives me the following errors:

```dart
Error: Dart2js does not currently support inheritance of the same class with different type arguments: Both P2PClient<Peer> and P2PClient<ProtocolPeer> are supertypes of _ProtocolP2PClient.
class _ProtocolP2PClient
^^^^^
```

I kind of know what the problem is:

- _P2PClient implements `P2PClient<Peer>`
- _ProtocolP2PClient implements `ProtocolP2PClient<ProtocolPeer>`

But I think that it's kind of the same if you look at it in detail:

ProtocolP2PClient will extend P2PClient with ProtocolPeer and because ProtocolPeer extends Peer, the interfaces actually don't differ. Is this just a limitation of dart2js and I should file a feature request or is there any other implementation I could come up with?

Comment: Looks like this bug http://dartbug.com/14729